# How can I get my Wandering Jew to flower?

Tags: houseplants, flowering

I have had a [Wandering Jew *(Tradescantia zebrina)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_zebrina) plant for several years, but it has never flowered.

- It is in a hanging basket outside during the warm season, and indoors during winter.
- The temperature gets down to 45°F (7°C) in Miracle Grow potting mix.
- It gets lots of water from the rain, but during the dry period I water it.
- I make [worm (compost) tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compost_tea) from my [vermicomposter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermicompost) and use that as a liquid fertilizer feed.

**Q.** What should be done to get it to flower?

Comment: Apparently there are three species of spiderwort that are called Wandering Jew. 1) _[Tradescantia pallida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_pallida)_ 2) _[Tradescantia fluminensis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_fluminensis)_ and 3) _[Tradescantia zebrina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_zebrina)_. From your description (houseplant, indoors during winter, hanging plant), it looks like _T. pallida_ and I've included the wiki link to that plant. If I'm mistaken, please correct the link accordingly

Comment: @jmusser When outside is it in a windy location? Outdoor or indoor is it ever subjected to temperatures below 50°F (10°C)? What potting medium is it planted in? How often do you water it & how much water per watering? Do you apply a fertilizer? If yes, what fertilizer, how much & how often? Also, could you please post a photo or two of the plant...

Comment: This is Zebrina Pendula. The temperature gets down to 45F in Miracle Grow potting mix. It gets lots of water from the rain, but during the dry period I water it. I apply compost tea from my vermicomposter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having read up a little on [*Tradescantia zebrina*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_zebrina):

- In cooler (non native) climates, flowers are a rare sight.

**Q.** What can you do to increase the chance of flowering?

- Plant requires plenty of light, but does best if kept out of direct sun (especially during the heat of Summer).
- Subjecting the plant to temperatures below 50°F (10°C) isn't recommended.
- Constant moisture during the growing season (Spring and Summer) is recommended.
- Reduce watering in the Autumn (Fall) and Winter.
- Potting medium should offer good drainage.
- Potting medium should be replaced once a year, early Spring is the best time of year to perform this operation.
- Once ever 3 to 4 weeks during the growing season apply a "mild" liquid fertilizer feed.

Comment: @jmusser From the [Wikipedia link above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_zebrina): "*Tradescantia zebrina*, formerly known as *Zebrina pendula*..."